# How to track user's gestures and taps across the entire app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, gestures

Does iOS 7/8 support tracking after user's gestures and taps across the entire app, without the need to literally listen on every view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by attaching a gesture recognizer to your [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html) in your `AppDelegate`. `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, and because it manages your views anyway you can attach a gesture recognizer here.

Conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your `AppDelegate`, attach whatever gesture recognizer you want to your `UIWindow` instance (of course set the delegate as well), and override the following:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    //do whatever with your touch
    return false;
}
```

Returning false is important, so that your code won't interfere with your regular app function; **but it is important to note** that because you have to return false, in order for this to work you must do all your [UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/) work in the location as noted above.